# Align inline-block to the right without using float

Tags: html, css

I'm using a content management system and I have setup the client with a class to make there own buttons by selecting text and applying the class. Now the client wants all the buttons to right align which is easy with a "float:right;" but it appears overlap any content below the button so I was wondering if anyone knows the fix or a better approach to this problem, keeping in mind its within a CMS which just applies a class to a p or span.

```
.LinkButtons {
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
background-color:#00649c;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;
float:right;
}

.LinkButtons:hover, .linkbuttons:hover {background-color:#00718b; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;}
.LinkButtons a, .linkbuttons a {color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
.LinkButtons a:hover, .linkbuttons a:hover {color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}

<p>Text above</p>
<p class="LinkButtons">MORE INFO</p>
<p>Text below gets the button overlapping due to the float floating over top</p>
```

Comment: It's not supposed to appear over content that's below it?

Comment: Sorry the float is causing it to overlap the content below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i've got what you mean.**[try this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8qqU/1/)**. You want the inline block element to clear all space on its left. This can be achieved by adding following rule to your CSS

```
.LinkButtons + p {
    clear: right;
}
```

This sets all `<p>` elements, that are next sibling of the said button, to *not allow anything on their right*. Of course you can modify this rule to accommodate other elements that you expect to appear after the button. Or you can do

```
.LinkButtons + * {
    clear: right;
}
```

for all :)

**Update**

Using this technique will not allow multiple buttons on same, use following if you want to put multiple buttons on same line.

```
/* Replace */
.LinkButtons + * {
    clear: right;
}

/* With */

.LinkButtons+:not(.LinkButtons){
    clear: right;
}
```

The rule only clears the right for elements that are no buttons themselves.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xemugyuz/)**

Comment: @kheya well the solution still solves OP's _original problem_i.e., `the buttons do not occupy space and appear to overlap the following content`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8qqU/

I made a wrapping div that had the inline button as a child.  I then used the `text-align` property and set it to "right" to align the button to the right.

**CSS:**

```
.LinkButtons {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
    background-color:#00649c;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px;
}

.align-right {
    text-align:right;
}

.LinkButtons:hover, .linkbuttons:hover {
    background-color:#00718b;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.LinkButtons a, .linkbuttons a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.LinkButtons a:hover, .linkbuttons a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>Text above</p>
<div class="align-right"><p class="LinkButtons">MORE INFO</p></div>
<p>Text below gets the button over top</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately the client cant create div's in the CMS, I have to achieve the alignment within one class applied to a p tag, it may not even be possible which I can accept.

Comment: This is a better solution